# How to add stripchart on a boxplot without outliers?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I made a `boxplot` without outliers.

```
boxplot(data, names = names(files), las = 2, outline=FALSE)
```

Now, I am trying to add `stripchart` on it:

```
stripchart(data, method = "jitter", add = T, col = "red")
```

Plot looks something like this:

[image: [Plot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsZzCdhRCQ3YkAIOnmUnEUMx8049)]

I understand the reason why plot is like this: because I have not plotted outliers with `boxplot`. How to add `stripchart` properly (without outliers)?

Comment: Why not considering first filtering those outliers from data?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want the plot to look like, or what the problem is here.

Comment: Thank you [Eric Lecoutre](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5558861/eric-lecoutre)

Comment: @gung Please ask for edits or suggest edits, instead demotivating new users by negative voting. You were also a beginner sometimes back.

Comment: @DeepakTanwar, I did ask for an edit.

Comment: @gung and within seconds, you assumed that I won't update and you put a negative vote for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

```
b <- boxplot(data, names = names(files), las = 2, outline=FALSE)
stripchart(data[!data %in% b$out], method = "jitter", add = T, col = "red",
           vertical = T)
```